# Given a message and signature, find a public key that makes the signature valid (ECDSA)

Tags: signature, dsa

This question is a variant on [Given a message and signature, find a public key that makes the signature valid](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8902/given-a-message-and-signature-find-a-public-key-that-makes-the-signature-valid), which discusses the analogous question for RSA.  It was suggested to me by [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24280/can-you-always-derive-a-public-bitcoin-address-from-a-message-and-a-random-signa#comment29177_24280) over on Bitcoin.SE.

Suppose we are given an ECDSA signature $S$, a message $M_1$, and a public key $P_1$, such that $S$ is a valid signature of $M_1$ with $P_1$.    Let $M_2$ be another message.  Is it known whether we can feasibly find another public key $P_2$ such that the same $S$ is also a valid signature of $M_2$ with $P_2$?

Is there a general name for this kind of an attack (on a general signature algorithm)?

What would be the practical implications of such an attack?  I can't think of any obvious way to use it to cause mischief, but I may just not be creative enough.

(Apologies if this is well-known or if my terminology or notation is bad.  I am a mathematician but not a cryptographer.)

**Edit**: Thanks to Ricky Demer for the link to the paper by Pornin and Stern (see comment below).  In their terminology, if I have it right, this attack is called a *second key construction*, and a vulnerable signature algorithm is said to lack *destructive exclusive ownership*.  They also describe a way that an attacker could use this to produce a fake revocation of a victim's X.509 certificate.

Comment: [related](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/2005-acns-pornin+stern.pdf) $\;$

Comment: Check out *4.1.6 Public Key Recovery Operation* in [Certicom - SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.secg.org/download/aid-780/sec1-v2.pdf)

Comment: See [ECDSA Signatures allow recovery of the public key on bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6430.0)

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, but this will allow to recover the public key corresponding to the signing key used for producing the signature at hand. Nate asks for $P_2\neq P_1$.

Comment: @RickyDemer: Thanks very much.  That paper seems to give a very good overview, and I've noted it in my question.

Comment: @DrLecter Can't you simply use the same algorithm, but using $M_2$ as input? I expect to get out some public key, but a public key where the corresponding private key isn't known by the attacker.

Comment: @CodesInChaos does this work out? I did not take a deeper look at this idea yet.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. We can easily generate the malicious public key as in DSS case.
The following attack was proposed in Section 4.5 of [Blake-Wilson and Menezes: Unknown Key-Share Attacks on the Station-to-Station (STS) Protocol (PKC 1999)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.1051).

Let $(G,q,n,P)$ be the ECDSA parameters, where $n$ is the order of the group $G$ over the elliptic curve and $P$ is a generator of $G$.

Let $P_1 = d_1 P$ be the public key, let $M_1$ be the message, and let $S_1 = (s_1, r_1)$ be the signature as you noted.

Since $S_1$ is a valid signature under the public key $P_1$, it satisfies the following equaitons.
$$ s_1 k_1 \equiv e_1 + d_1 r_1 \pmod{n},$$
where $e_1$ is a digest of the message $M_1$, and $r_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a $x$-coordinate of $k_1 P$ modulo $n$.

### How to construct a malicious public key

Let $M_2$ be the target message.
We now virtually compute a malicious secret key $d_2$ as
$$ d_2 = r_1^{-1} (s_1 k_1 - e_2) \bmod{n}, $$
where $e_2$ is a digest of the message $M_2$.
We then compute a malicious public key $P_2 = d_2 P$, which is 
$$ r_1^{-1} (s_1 k_1 - e_2) P = r_1^{-1} (e_1 + d_1 r_1 - e_2) P = r_1^{-1}(e_1 - e_2)P + P_1$$.

#### Validity of the public key $P_2$.

The public key $P_2$ makes the message $M_2$ and the signature $S_1 = (s_1, r_1)$ valid.
Let us verify the validity of them.

1. $r_1$ and $s_1$ is in the range $[1,n-1]$, because the signature $S_1$ is valid.
2. Let $X = u_1 P + u_2 P_2$, where $u_1 = e_2 s_1^{-1} \bmod{n}$ and $u_2 = r_1 s_1^{-1} \bmod{n}$.
   By the construction of $P_2$, we have $X = (u_1 + u_2 d_2) P = s_1^{-1} (e_2 + r_1 d_2) P = s_1^{-1} (s_1 k_1) P = k_1 P$.
   Therefore, $r_1$ is the $x$-coordinate of $X$.

### How to prevent this attack

It is easy to prevent this attack.
We just use a digest $e' = \mathrm{Hash}(pk,M)$ instead of $e = \mathrm{Hash}(M)$.

Comment: Usefully, the change you describe would also stop a hash collision from immediately yielding $\hspace{.9 in}$ a way to violate unforgeability for every public key. $\;$

Comment: The signature $S_1 = (s_1,k_1)$ is not a signature. The signature should be $S_1 = (r_1,s_1)$ as the knowledge of $k_1$ leads to the private key $d_1$.
The attacker has no knowledge of $k_1$ and can't perform this attack.
See the [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25044/15312)  by @ggutoski which provides more details.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Well, I correct the form of the signature. But, please notice that the attack I described does not require knowledge of $k_1$.

Answer (score 4):

An attack is described in Section 4.1.6 of the [SEC1](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) document.

Regarding [xagawa's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15561/23934):

1. The attack you describe is different from that described in Section 4.5 of the Blake-Wilson--Menezes paper.  Specifically, their attack: (a) does not require knowledge of the secret ephemeral key $k$, and (b) changes the reference point $P$, which is not allowed in some instantiations of ECDSA.
2. Your attack requires knowledge of the secret ephemeral key $k$, which is equivalent to knowing the private key $d$.

These comments on [xagawa's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15561/23934) should be in a separate comment on that answer but I don't have enough reputation so instead I included them here.